# Bind IP address per ejb exposed as web service - jboss

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

How can I run ejbs exposed as a web services on the same jboss (version 4.2.3) using different IPs.

For example:
I have two web service locations (two different ejb components) and one server with two network interfaces:

```
http://192.168.0.1/test/TestService1

http://192.168.0.1/test/TestService2
```

and I want to have this:

```
http://192.168.0.1/test/TestService1

http://192.168.0.2/test/TestService2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If JBoss is anything similar to websphere in it's architecture, I think you'll have two create to separate server instances and bind each to a specific IP. Then you'll deploy the EJB:s to the respective instance bound to the desired IP.

Comment: This is not option, because these two services share the same cache and also call themselves internally. The second thing could be solved through remote interfaces, but the problem is that I am not granted to change the source code, only configuration.

Comment: Well, you could use an http proxy in front of your JBoss. Apache with mod_proxy should work. Then you set it up to proxy your 0.2 address to 0.1. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html